# jQuery not loading in Rails 3.2.6 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using **Rails 3.2.6** and the **application.js** file under **app/assets/javascripts** is being linked in my `<head>` by `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`. In **application.js** after

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I have added

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('doc ready');
})
```

Just to test if it is working because making a new javascript file **my.js** in the same directory is not compiling into **application.js** (which is a whole other problem entirely). In my javascript console I am seeing an error **"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"**. In Terminal I did a `gem list` and I see `jquery-rails (3.0.4)`. In my **Gemfile** I see **gem 'jquery-rails'**.

Why is jQuery not being loaded properly into my app?

**UPDATE:** As I said, when I type `gem list` in Terminal I see `jquery-rails (3.0.4)`. However, when I type `bundle install` I see `Using jquery-rails (2.1.3)`. Could there be some sort of conflict causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Is your asset pipeline disabled?  If it is, you need to run a rake task to get jQuery installed.

From the jquery-rails GitHub page:

Rails 3.1 or greater (with asset pipeline enabled)

The jquery and jquery-ujs files will be added to the asset pipeline and available for you to use. If they're not already in app/assets/javascripts/application.js by default, add these lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

For jQuery UI, we recommend the jquery-ui-rails gem, as it includes the jquery-ui css and allows easier customization. This gem still packages the jQuery UI javascript for compatibility. To use it, add the following line to your application.js:

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

In order to use the themed parts of jQuery UI, you will also need to supply your own theme CSS (or use the jquery-ui-rails gem mentioned above).

Rails 3.0 (or greater with asset pipeline disabled)

This gem adds a single generator: jquery:install. Running the generator will remove any Prototype JS files you may happen to have, and copy jQuery and the jQuery-ujs driver for Rails (and optionally, jQuery UI) to the public/javascripts directory.

This gem will also hook into the Rails configuration process, removing Prototype and adding jQuery to the javascript files included by the javascript_include_tag(:defaults) call. While this gem contains the minified and un-minified versions of jQuery and jQuery UI, only the minified versions are included in :defaults.

To invoke the generator, run:

```
rails generate jquery:install #--ui to enable jQuery UI
```

You're done!

Docs:  https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails

Comment: Thanks. The pipeline is enabled. This was the result of the `generate` command: `deprecated  You are using Rails 3.1 with the asset pipeline enabled, so this generator is not needed.
              The necessary files are already in your asset pipeline.`

Comment: Did you get this figured out?  If not, if you want to chat on SO, we could keep troubleshooting.

Comment: I haven't gotten it working. What is weird too is if I replace `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` with something like `<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" %>` I get the same error. Maybe it is not necessarily a problem with the pipeline? I'd be up for chatting about this if you are available today.